# How to get Refresh Token in Postman in 2024?

Tags: oauth2, httprequest, post, refresh-token, postman

I've been trying to get the refresh token using Postman without success. It seems from what I've found that some ways have changed over the years. I do have the request to get the access token, which is the first step I needed.

How do I obtain the refresh token? Why does it seem so complicated? Why doesn't it come in the same request?

I have enabled all scopes for my App and turned the following options to on:

- Enable Client Credentials Flow
- Enable Authorization Code and Credentials Flow
- Require user credentials in the POST body for Authorization Code and Credentials Flow

This is my Access token request in Postman

[image]

**List of available (and selected) OAuth Scopes**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only certain flows provide you with a refresh token, and the Client Credentials flow is not one of them.

- The User-Agent flow (a.k.a. the "implicit" flow/grant type) can return a refresh token if you add `refresh_token` as a scope to the request for the access token (or have your connected app configured to have that scope).
- The Web-Server flow (a.k.a. the "authorization code" flow/grant type) can also return a refresh token.
- Documentation seems to also indicate that the Hybrid App flow can also return a refresh token, but I have 0 experience with that one.

And as far as I know, that is a complete list. As usual, referencing the official documentation on [the OAuth Authorization flows](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_flows.htm&type=5) is a good place to start.

Comment: How do I add the `refresh_token` scope to the request? I have enabled all avaiilable scopes, and `refresh_token` is not one of them

Comment: I updated my question with the list of available (and selected) OAuth scopes

Comment: @Z0q By adding another key-value pair to the body in postman (key = "scope", value = "refresh_token"). Like the documentation says though, the "scope" parameter is optional. If your connected app has the "Perform Requests at Any Time" scope (a combo of `refresh_token` and `offline_access`), then you don't need to do that. And one more time, just in case, **you cannot obtain a refresh token through the client credentials flow**. Salesforce will not include it, and the relevant RFC recommends not including it in that particular flow.